# Why is a "bindingRedirect" added to the app.config file after adding the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, base-class-library

I was wondering why nuget added the following code to my applications `app.config` file, after installing the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

If I remove this XML-element from the config, the app will not work properly.

As far as I understand it, we can use the `bindingRedirect` to make the app load a newer or older version of an assembly in case the version we were using when compiling the EXE is gone.
However I am using exactly the version `2.5.19.0`, why would I need a redirect then?

[image: the version of my dll]

***Why* do I need this `bindingRedirect`?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The assemblies `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks` and `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` are still referencing v1.5.11.0 of `System.Runtime` and `System.Threading.Tasks`.

Without the `bindingRedirect`, the `Microsoft.*` assemblies would try to load an old version of the `System.*` assemblies, which would fail.

Comment: I have a similar situation, where the redirected assembly is not used else where at all, but the bindingredirect is still needed? -- or can I assert that if the old version of the assembly is not referenced anywhere then the bindingredirect is not needed at all.

Answer (score 11):

You are simply saying whenever there is older version that is between **0.0.0.0 to 2.5.19.0**, please replace that version with the new version that is 2.5.19.0

Let's say you don't have the older version available in your project and you are trying to access it, then you will end up with an error like "System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly"

So when your project is looking for an older version of that DLL it will simply replace that  with new one which is available